# PHP: about using echo

Tags: php, echo

I writed `<?php echo '<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="mt">asdasddddd </br>';
?>` in a HTML file.

but it always tell me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO`

I found some instructions, but dont know what's wrong with this sntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: strange.. are you using a condition? or anything which requires `{`

Comment: This line of code seems valid. Could you please post the entire HTML page ? The issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: That should not be echoed anyway. Just surround it with condition, if you are using one, if not than you have even weaker reason to echo it.

Comment: Remove the PHP in this example, you don't have anything dynamical which you need to put in PHP

Comment: Why use `echo`  at all? Why not `<?='some data'?>` - or even simple plain output without PHP?

Comment: Guys, it seems pretty obvious that this is just a test, don't you think ?... And it's should not eraise any error. So the problem is somewhere else in the page.

Answer (score 5):

The actual error is somewhere above. The most common thing is an unclosed semicolon (`;`)

Comment: @user2764080: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it (when [so] lets you), by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.